# Clearing layers from view crashes app on next iteration

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pretty simple app right now. I draw lines where the users fingers go, when they lift there finger I want to clear the drawing, and when they draw again show the new lines.

However, when I clear the lines the first time, the next press causes a crash with no error message. I figure i'm doing something small wrong but can't figure it out. Here is my code:

I get a EXC__BAD_ACCESS message

```
 var prevX: CGFloat!
var prevY: CGFloat!

var startX: CGFloat = 150
var startY : CGFloat = 450

var reset: Bool = true

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:")
    pan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    pan.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

func pan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print(self.view.layer)
    var state = recognizer.state

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        reset = true
        var sublayers = self.view.layer.sublayers
        for layer in sublayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
    } else {
        var interval = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if (reset) {
            reset = false
            prevX = CGFloat(startX + interval.x)
            prevY = CGFloat(startY + interval.y)
        }
        var newPointX = startX + interval.x
        var newPointY = startY + interval.y

        var path = UIBezierPath().bezierPathByReversingPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: prevX, y: prevY))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:newPointX, y:newPointY))

        var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        prevX = newPointX
        prevY = newPointY

    }
}
```

I'm not really sure where the stack trace appears. I put a print statement at the top of pan callback and that DOES NOT get called, so I don't think it happens in that. It just opens up

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
```

Giving the message Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1, address=0x499e....

A little bit more, with the error message at the top message:

```
___UIApplicationExtensionGetAccurateShareServicesExtensionForIdentifier_block_invoke_2
0x18c00e3c0:  adrp   x8, 54568
0x18c00e3c4:  ldr    x8, [x8, #2248]
0x18c00e3c8:  ldr    x8, [x8]
0x18c00e3cc:  ldr    x9, [sp, #56]
0x18c00e3d0:  sub    x8, x8, x9
0x18c00e3d4:  cbnz   x8, 0x18c00e3fc           ; UIApplicationMain + 1548
0x18c00e3d8:  movz   w0, #0
```

I know it's something this line is doing:

```
            for layer in sublayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
```

because if I remove it it works fine (just doesn't clear the previous line)

Comment: Please indicate where you get the exception.

Comment: I'm not even really sure. It DOES NOT enter the pan callback. I put a print statement at the start and it does not appear. I updated the question with the stack trace

Comment: This looks like a really bad way to do drawing. Why are you adding a new bezier path and layer every time you move your finger?

Comment: @rdelmar well I want to draw a line showing where the user moved their finger, what's a better way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it that requires a lot less code, and only uses one layer. You don't need to remove that layer, only its path.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var path: UIBezierPath!
    var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
    }


    func pan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        if recognizer.state == .Began {
            let loc = recognizer.locationInView(view)
            path = UIBezierPath()
            path.moveToPoint(loc)

        }else if recognizer.state == .Changed {
            var loc = recognizer.locationInView(view)
            path.addLineToPoint(loc)
            shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath

        }else if recognizer.state == .Ended {
            shapeLayer.path = nil
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that there were already sublayers for `view` and you are removing those along with the ones you added.  You only want to remove the sublayers you added.  I added a `myLayers` array to hold the new sublayers, and use that to remove the added sublayers:

```
var prevX: CGFloat!
var prevY: CGFloat!

var startX: CGFloat = 150
var startY : CGFloat = 450

var reset: Bool = true
var myLayers: [CAShapeLayer] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var pan = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "pan:")
    pan.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    pan.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(pan)
}

func pan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    print(self.view.layer)
    var state = recognizer.state

    if (state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended) {
        reset = true

        for layer in myLayers {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
        }
        myLayers = []
    } else {
        var interval = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if (reset) {
            reset = false
            prevX = CGFloat(startX + interval.x)
            prevY = CGFloat(startY + interval.y)
        }
        var newPointX = startX + interval.x
        var newPointY = startY + interval.y

        var path = UIBezierPath().bezierPathByReversingPath()
        path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: prevX, y: prevY))
        path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x:newPointX, y:newPointY))

        var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path.CGPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        myLayers.append(shapeLayer)

        prevX = newPointX
        prevY = newPointY

    }
}
```